# Get information about text from other device (via Bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard

I have a barcode scanner that my phone recognizes as a keyboard. They connect via bluetooth.
I need some action in my application after reading the barcode. I don't want to add a input because it will break the whole appearance of the app. I tried to create something on my own, but it only worked because EditText was in the view (interestingly, it entered text even when the field was disabled)

Is it possible to check what text was typed by the keyboard without using inputs?

Answer (score 1):

you can override `onKeyDown` in `Activity` and check which keys were pressed

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("onKeyDown", "key pressed code:" + keyCode); // log your key codes
    return true; // returning true means event handled
}
```

in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent) you can check all codes, besides that there is also `onKeyUp` method, may be useful. powodzenia

Comment: Ok. It is work. But is possible to do something similar in service?

Comment: kind of... generally no, `Service` doesn't have `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` methods, so can't intercept keys, but there is a "special kind" of `Service`s, called [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), which can intercept keys even when your app is in background ("homed"). but be careful with this `Service` usage, Google Play refuse to publish your app if you don't have serious purpose for using it (and you don't, you can still operate on `Activity`s level). besides that: this `Service` can be enabled only by user

Comment: Ok, onKeyDown is not what I want. Can I check in service that string come to phone via Bluetooth?

Comment: afaik thats not possible

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It is possible to get data from other device and not use Activity. And here what I do:

```
val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    val pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
    if (pairedDevice.isNotEmpty()) {
        val device = pairedDevice.first()
        val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket = device.javaClass.getMethod(
            "createRfcommSocket", Int::class.javaPrimitiveType
        ).invoke(device, 1) as BluetoothSocket // I had problem with connection with my device and this is only way to connect via Bluetooth
        try {
            if (mmSocket.isConnected) mmSocket.close() else mmSocket.connect()
            readData(mmSocket)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            mmSocket.close()
        }
    }
```

And readData function:

```
while (mmSocket.isConnected) {
        val inputStream = mmSocket.inputStream
        val available = inputStream.available()
        val bytes = ByteArray(available)
        
        inputStream.read(bytes, 0, available)
        val barcode = String(bytes)
        
        if (barcode.isNotBlank()) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                textView?.text = barcode //display result on UI
            }
        }
    }
```